# minimize js files in gradle build while creating a war

Tags: javascript, java, gradle, groovy, gradle-plugin

I am completely new to gradle and I am manage to create war through gradle-4.2.1 by following scripts :

```
apply plugin: 'war'
archivesBaseName = "idcapture"
version = '1.0' 
webAppDirName = 'WebContent'
buildDir = 'gradle_Build'

 sourceSets {
  main {
     java {
          srcDir 'src'
     }
     resources {
       srcDir 'conf'
     }
  } 
}

dependencies {
  compile fileTree(dir: "WebContent/WEB-INF/lib", include: '*.jar')
   }
```

I can able to create an war file by above code but my intention the war file should have minimized version of JS files. Hence I have tried n number of places. 
I tried erwin js plugin and I am unable to implement:
fyr, [https://github.com/eriwen/gradle-js-plugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTGFJ.png)

Especially I  am not able to point the js file paths and minimize function my script. The errors are various and I am not sure where to place that in my script!!
Fyr, my application folder structure attached

[image: main project folder structure]
[image: js folder structure]

any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it, if we add following erwil libs on any place of the build. it works fine:

```
    plugins {
    id 'com.eriwen.gradle.js' version '2.14.1'
}


import com.eriwen.gradle.js.tasks.MinifyJsTask
task minifyJS << {
    println "lets minify"
  fileTree('WebContent/js').eachWithIndex { file, index ->
    def dynamicTask = "minify$index"
    task "$dynamicTask" (type: MinifyJsTask) {
      source = file
      dest = file
    }
    tasks."$dynamicTask".execute()
  }
}
```